# Adding multiple relations in eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**My application:** In my application users have the possibility to predict the scores of upcoming soccer games. So basically there is a relationship between the `user` and `predictions`, but there is also a relationship between the `prediction` and my `Match model`. Currently I add the `homeTeamName` & `awayTeamName` in my prediction table but this is not really necessary since I store my `match_id` in my predictions table. I want to load my team names from my `match table` based on the `match_id` from my prediction table instead of adding the names in the predictions table.

Here is a look at my relations:

**Match model**

```
class Match extends Model
{
    public function Predictions() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Prediction'); // one match has many predictions
    }
}
```

**Prediction model**

```
class Prediction extends Model
{
   public function User() {

       return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); // prediction belongs to a user
   }

   public function Match() {

       return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'match_id', 'match_id'); // prediction belongs to a match
   }
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function Predictions() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Prediction'); // a user has many predictions
    }

}
```

**Using lazy eager loading for this query**

```
public function showPredictions() {
    \DB::enableQueryLog();
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->load('predictions', 'predictions.match'); 

    dd(\DB::getQueryLog());

    return view('predictions', compact('user'));
}
```

**output**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 13.0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `predictions` where `predictions`.`user_id` in (?)"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 1.0
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `matches` where `matches`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:10 [▼
      0 => 233133
      1 => 233134
      2 => 233135
      3 => 233136
      4 => 233137
      5 => 233138
      6 => 233139
      7 => 233140
      8 => 233141
      9 => 233142
    ]
    "time" => 1.0
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax

```
$user->load('predictions', 'predictions.match')->where('status', 'SCHEDULED');
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but when I dd this I get following: `#relations: array:1 [▼
        "match" => null
      ]` shouldn't I receive all my columns for that match_id?

Comment: It's working, I checked. Can you share your tables dump? https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=TzGJCfSnQ4 here is a link to my sql structure

Comment: I think the problem in a foreign key. 
`...
   public function Match() {

       return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'match_id'); // prediction belongs to a 
...`
I mean you should to specify foreign key

Comment: Try this code `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $user->load('predictions', 'predictions.match')->where('status', 'SCHEDULED'); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`
and share output

Comment: I updated my question with the output, also added the match id to the relationship, still getting no records

Comment: return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'match_id', 'match_id'); I'm sure it will fix your problem

Comment: This works! I don't really understand why there is need to specify the match_id twice

Comment: Your match_id in prediction table refer to match_id in match table. If you don't specify $foreignKey and $otherKey in belongsTo method laravel resolve it as $foreignKey='predictions.match_id' and $otherKey='matches.id'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user->load([
   'predictions.match' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'SCHEDULED');
    }
]);
```

Or if you have `status` column in both tables:

```
$user->load([
   'predictions.match' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('predictions.status', 'SCHEDULED');
    }
]);
```